# How to create timestamp variable in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, logging, timestamp

I am trying to create a timestamp variable which actually stores the present time and outputs the time at that instance. A reproducible code is also included:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
t = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(2)
    print t
```

**Output**

```
2015-03-11 11:28:53
2015-03-11 11:28:53
2015-03-11 11:28:53
2015-03-11 11:28:53
2015-03-11 11:28:53
```

**Desired output**

```
2015-03-11 11:28:53
2015-03-11 11:28:55
2015-03-11 11:28:57
2015-03-11 11:28:59
2015-03-11 11:29:01
```

Any easy way to do this instead of placing the command

```
datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

multiple times in the code.

Comment: Why would a *string* object update itself in a loop? Why not simply use `print datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` in the loop itself?

Comment: If you want to capture the current time at specific moments, you'll *have* to call `datetime.now()` to measure the current time.

Comment: I have to use it at multiple locations, makes the code look very messy.

Comment: Then put it in a function you call.

Comment: Wouldn't there be a time lag, between the function call and function output?

Comment: You are printing time at the *second level* and you are worried about the overhead of calling a function? We are talking nanoseconds here.

Comment: Or to put it another way: if you are worried about the overhead of calling a function, why are you creating a new `datetime` object then formatting that object to a string each time? Why are you not using `timeit.default_time` and worry about converting that number to a precise timestamp later? Why are you using Python at all if this is time critical?

Comment: `t = lambda: datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` `print(t())` will also work.

Comment: note: `logging` module can include the timestamp automatically in whatever time format you'd like.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot avoid having to call `datetime.now()` if you need to capture the current time at different moments.

Put the call in a function if you feel it is too verbose to repeat:

```
def current_time():
    return datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

then call that:

```
for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(2)
    print current_time()
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `t=...` line into the `for` loop and/or condense it into the `print` statement and/or wrap it into a separate function then call that in the `for` loop.

The latter is going to be a best practice way of doing it if you're going to be using it in other places in the code. It means you only have to change the formatting or time call in a single place in your code.